# Presence of planets in Milky Way and other galaxies

Tags: planets, galaxies

Are there only planets in the Milky Way galaxy, or are there other planets in other galaxies?

If planets are only in the Milky Way, why aren't there planets in others?

Comment: Come on... Really? You couldn't bother to google 'planet'? Here you go... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planet.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not meet the minimum level of research effort to make for an acceptable question.

Comment: I would agree that there is little research effort, but I can understand the motivations for asking it. After all, how many extra-galactic planets have we found? Logic says that there should be as many in every other galaxy as there are in the Milky Way, but we haven't had much success finding them. But yes, logic would answer the question pretty well. By the way, why not ask this on the Astronomy SE in the first place (note: not a suggestion)?

Comment: @Danu I couldn't find this specific point on the Wikipedia page either. This is a reasonable enough (if simple question).

Comment: @EmilioPisanty It wasn't the right page to link to really... [Exoplanets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exoplanet) and [extragalactic planets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extragalactic_planet) are the better pages to read.

Comment: I never understood the fascination with existence of planets outside the solar system. Isn't it common sense that any matter that doesn't turn into a star will turn into something else? And clearly if it's large enough it'd be a planet...

Comment: @Mehrdad: I think the fascination is twofold. (1) we've only just developed technology to detect them, so it's a growth industry just now. (2) we're interested to know how common earth-like planets are, because we're interested in life and the only kind of life we can confidently predict is possible, is the kind of life we see on earth. Note that finding extrasolar gas giants is already pretty boring to general news reporters, they want a better chance of liquid water than ever before or they're not running it. Planets with exotic chemistry also stand a chance, e.g. giant diamonds ;-)

Comment: Strictly speaking, there are only eight planets in the entire universe: Mercury, Venus, Earth, Mars, Jupiter, Saturn, Uranus, and Neptune. All those orbiting thingies scientists have been discovering as of late? Those aren't planets. They're "exoplanets". The IAU definition of a planet is rather heliocentric. That said, a rose by any other name smells just as sweet. Those orbiting thingies discovered as of late *are* planets, and they reveal that there truly is no reason to think the solar system is unique. And there's no more reason to thing the Milky Way is unique, either.

Comment: @Danu and everyone else, let me link to [this ongoing meta discussion](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6001/closing-insufficient-effort-questions)

Answer (score 12):

Observing planets in other galaxies is *really* hard to do because they are so far away and planets are so small. One of our closest neighbors, the [Andromeda Galaxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andromeda_Galaxy) (also called M31), is about $10^{19}$ km away (just under 780 [kpc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsec)), so finding a planet the size of Jupiter (roughly $10^5$ km diameter) is pretty tough (radius to distance is very small). Even the closer neighbors, the Magellanic clouds at distances of [50](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_Magellanic_Cloud) and [60 kpc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_Magellanic_Cloud) (LMC & SMC respectively), are still over $10^{18}$ km away so finding planets orbiting stars there are equally challenging.

It has been proposed that one can use [microlensing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_microlensing) to detect (large) planets orbiting stars. Some people have [claimed to have found a star](http://arxiv.org/abs/0906.1050) with an gravitational lensing aberration that *could* be the result of a planet. This is really a guessing game because the resolution is, at best, a few pixels on a CCD.

We do not believe that the Milky Way galaxy is unique in its development of planets, especially given the findings of the [Kepler mission](http://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/kepler/overview/) (prior to its failure) that there's roughly 1.6 planets per star. But we can't really say that there is indeed planets in other galaxies simply because we haven't had observations confirming the hypothesis.

Comment: It's difficult to take this question seriously, but it does have merit, I suppose, if we hadn't observed planets from other galaxies, but hasn't measuring the effects of planetary transit on the light emitted from far away stars shown that they do have objects orbiting them? How about the effect planets have on the motion of the stars?

Comment: The light transit is unobservable due to the extreme distances, the only hypothetical way is the gravitational lensing mentioned in the 2nd paragraph. I don't know that we can even really track the *positions* of the stars well enough to apply Kepler's laws.

Comment: Using gravitational lensing is still giving inconsistent results. Recently there was some hype over finding several exo-planets in a single solar system (Gliese 581 star system) that were later decided to be calculation errors (at least for the most promising exo-planets). Here's a link to the article I read: http://arstechnica.com/science/2014/07/two-of-the-exoplanets-closest-to-earth-dont-actually-exist/.

Comment: @Jasper: Yes, it is unreliable because it is basically a one-pixel shift in the CCD image.

Comment: Our closest neighbors are Magellanic Clouds (LMC&SMC) and some other dwarf galaxies. M31 is much farther than those. I don't want to downvote your answer but please fix this mistake. By the way, some methods for finding extrasolar planets would probably work for Magellanic Clouds as well.

Comment: @firtree: You are right, so I've corrected that.

Comment: Now `so finding stars there are equally challenging` seems like typo: finding _planets_. Stars are resolved in Magellanic Clouds very easily.

Comment: @firtree: No way, it totally says `so finding planets orbiting stars there are equally challenging`. No idea where you got that :$

Comment: Well, it's not like we can see M-dwarfs very well in the Magellanic clouds (or even in most of our own galaxy). And certainly we can't see fainter things like white dwarfs.

Comment: @ChrisWhite I wear glasses and I live in a large city in the Northern Hemisphere, so I don't see Magellanic Clouds at all :-)

Comment: @ChrisWhite By the way, are Sun-like G-dwarfs resolved in Magellanic Clouds, or only brighter stars are?